# Transform all factor columns to the same factor

Tags: r, survey

I've got the following survey data (example):

```
 df <- data.frame(
   Q1 = c("1 = very bad", 2, "5 = very good", 4, 3),
   Q2 = c(2, 3, "1 = very bad", "5 = very good", NA),
   Q3 = c(0.5, 2.3, 4.5, 4.6, 2), #The average of Q1 and Q2, which are 
                                  #questions of the same category
   Q4 = c("Strongly disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
        "Strongly disagree")
)
```

But with about 350 questions and 500.000 answers. To summarize all the answers, I want all the factor columns to be in the form

```
  as.factor(c(1:5))
```

I've found out that

```
 levels(df$Q1) <- as.factor(c(1:5))
```

does the job. However, with over 300 columns, I don't want to do it manually and I can't seem to manage to do this for all columns which are a factor. I'm searching for an `apply`-kind of function which first recognizes a column as a factor and then changes its levels to be `1:5`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We can create an index for the `factor` columns, loop through the subset of dataset with `lapply`, specify the `levels`

```
i1 <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], factor, levels = 1:5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond! Unfortunately, this way the input `1 = Very bad` and `5 = Very good`  and column Q3 get to be `NA`.

Comment: @Kasper  But that is not the way your code showed i.e. `levels(df$Q1) <- as.factor(c(1:5))`

Comment: yes, when I do `levels(df$Q1) <- as.factor(c(1:5))` all the levels in the column turn nicely into 1-5. Your way gives me a column filled with NA.. I just tried a few things out and `levels(df[2]) <- as.factor(c(1:5))` doesn't do the job either. Maybe it has something to do with that?